# Display comments only in specific categories

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, categories

I am trying to enable comments only in specific categories.
Ex//
Events  Category ID=17
Videos Category ID=15

I tried this code with only one category listed.

`<?php if (!in_category('17')) comments_template(); ?>`

But yet the comments disappear instead...
I thought that code was to ONLY display comments if in a specific category?
And when I add multiple category IDs like so,

`<?php if (!in_category('17, 15')) comments_template(); ?>`
 it stops working...

I'd like to have more than 1 category display comments...
Not only one. But it seems the code above is only to REMOVE comments from that category...

What is the correct code?

**EDIT//**
Not sure if this information if useful..but these are all sub-categories that I wish to display and not display comments on.

Comment: I'm not a WordPress expert, but both these functions seem to be specific for your theme, can you tell us which theme you are using so we can check what these functions are doing?

Comment: also, your second code version should be `in_category('17', '15')` you are missing the single quotes near the comma

Comment: I actually created this theme on my own. Is there any file that would help? I can paste the HTML in a pastebin... @emartel

Comment: well `in_category` would be nice to see, what does it take as a parameter? where does it check the category of the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php if (in_category('15') || in_category('17')) comments_template(); ?>
```

Comment: This code will ONLY show comments within these categories right? If I wanted to add even more categories could I just add this `|| in_category('')` again?

Comment: first you try this and later you just have to add one more || in_category('') and that will work fine